# Shell script to create a yml file removes data after "$"

Tags: vi, cat

I am trying to create a yml file from a shell script which includes a sql query.
This is the sample script

```
cat <<EOF>/test/queryTest.yml

This is a test
sql: "select * from schema.table$name"
```

After I run the shell script and check the yml file, anything after "$" is removed
This is my yml

```
This is a test
sql: select * from schema.table
```

I would appreciate any thoughts on how to avoid this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape ("\") the $ sign.

```
cat <<EOF>/test/queryTest.yml

This is a test
sql: "select * from schema.table\$name"
```